# has_perms_by_name returns 1 for system stored proc that user has NO permission for

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, how is it possible that

```
select has_perms_by_name('sp_grantlogin', 'object', 'execute')
```

...returns 1, but calling sp_grantlogin from the same Windows user returns

```
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_grantlogin, Line 13
User does not have permission to perform this action
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct.

The user has permission to execute the stored procedure but the code inside the stored procedure throws that error when it is executed.

You can inspect the stored procedure code with

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_grantlogin'
```

Which shows

```
-- CHECK PERMISSIONS --
IF ( NOT is_srvrolemember('securityadmin') = 1 )
  BEGIN
      DBCC auditevent (105, 1, 0, @loginame, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

      RAISERROR(15247,-1,-1)

      RETURN ( 1 )
  END
```

To see what error 15247 is you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.messages
WHERE message_id = 15247 and language_id = 1033
```

Which returns

> User does not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that the stored proc can only be run by securityadmin, I did not know it was actually checked in the code. Thank you for this thorough and accurate answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `sysadmin` and `securityadmin` server roles are enabled in SQL Server Management Studio.

To do so, do the following from within SQL Server Management Studio:

- Connect to the database the user belongs to
- Expand the node for your database
- Expand the node labelled, `Security`
- Expand the node labelled, `Login`
- Right-click the username in the list
- Click on server roles
- Enable `securityadmin` by clicking the checkbox
- Enable `sysadmin` by clicking the checkbox